# Cant create dart server template shelf

Tags: dart

When I try to

> dart create -t server-shelf smoody_gamific

I get this error. Why I dont have server template? how can I get it

```
server-shelf" is not an allowed value for option "template".
Available templates:
  console-simple: A simple command-line application. (default)
    console-full: A command-line application sample.
  package-simple: A starting point for Dart libraries or applications.
      web-simple: A web app that uses only core Dart libraries.
```

Comment: What version of dart are you using? If you enter `dart --version` what does it say? I am on  `Dart SDK version: 2.15.0 (stable)`, and `server-shelf ` is showing as a template for me.